# Make "view" a synonym of "views"?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I noticed some users marked questions with the [view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/view) tag instead of the widely used [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) tag which already has the synonyms [views-2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-2), [views-3](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-3).

With Views being such a popular module it would make the most sense to ensure [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've approved the synonym you suggested, and merged the tags.

Comment: Great, thanks :)